# While clearing all the warnings from console it shows "You are loading @emotion/react when it is already loaded. Running multiple instances.."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, console, warnings

I am using react 18.2.0 and my react select version is 5.7.3 and the application throws a warning like this "You are loading @emotion/react when it is already loaded. Running multiple instances may cause problems. This can happen if multiple versions are used, or if multiple builds of the same version are used."  and can't be resolved

I have tried npm ls and returned this:

```
├── @reduxjs/toolkit@1.9.5
├── @testing-library/jest-dom@5.16.5
├── @testing-library/react@13.4.0
├── @testing-library/user-event@13.5.0
├── @wac-ui-dashboard/wac_component_library@0.1.11
├── axios@1.4.0
├── bootstrap@5.2.3
├── formik@2.4.1
├── react-bootstrap@2.7.4
├── react-datepicker@4.12.0
├── react-dom@18.2.0
├── react-hot-toast@2.4.1
├── react-icons@4.9.0
├── react-redux@8.0.7
├── react-router-dom@6.11.2
├── react-scripts@5.0.1
├── react-select@5.7.3
├── react@18.2.0
├── sass@1.62.1
├── web-vitals@2.1.4
└── yup@1.2.0
```